# Can you really "rewind/reverse" the debugger in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

When you are stepping through Swift code in Xcode (9/10?), there is a green bar on the right with something like:

[image]

You are supposed to be able to drag the partial-hamburger-menu upwards to rewind the statement pointer to re-run code. However, every time I try it it moves back as expected, but then 100% of the time I step from that point I get:
[image]

Is there a trick to this?

Comment: Working example: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/412/?time=1112

Answer (score 0):

You can move the pointer to the next statement to be executed to either a previously executed statement or a not-yet-executed statement, but in order for that to work the stack needs to be in the correct state, and so do the variables in memory.

In my experience, the outcome is usually  a crash.

You'd need to drop down to the assembler code and examine it in order to figure out what's really going on, and might need to patch variables and/or the contents of the stack in order for your code to survive the change of program counter. I've never invested the time to try to do that, however. As a result I find the feature pretty much useless, and have given up on it. (I've worked in assembler a LOT in years past, but never learned enough about ARM assembler to be able to read it well, much less hack registers, memory, and the stack to make moving the program counter work.)